# how search worked in this link? dynamic dropdown can be dynamically called from database?

Tags: javascript, php, search, dynamic, drop-down-menu

http://www.nepaltouragency.com/

I view its source code, I am also doing travel site and wish to have similar dynamic drop down accessing my database; not writing manually.

Here is the source code of that site; is it possible that the value comes dynamically once user select country, the related field comes? If yes can you send some tutorial links or some codes?

```
 <div class="tf-wrap">
                    <form action="/Search/">
                      <input type="hidden" name="z_CountryCode" id="z_CountryCode" value="LIKE" />
                      <select name="x_CountryCode" class="tf-select" onchange="TCN_reload(this)">
                        <option value="" selected="selected">All Country</option>
                      </select>
                      <input type="hidden" name="z_ActivitiesID" id="z_ActivitiesID" value="=" />
                      <select name="x_ActivitiesID" class="tf-select" onchange="TCN_reload(this)">
                        <option value="" selected="selected">All Services</option>
                      </select>
                      <input type="hidden" name="z_AreaID" id="z_AreaID" value="=" />
                      <select name="x_AreaID" class="tf-select" onchange="TCN_reload(this)">
                        <option value="" selected="selected">All Area</option>
                      </select>
                      <input type="hidden" name="z_Duration" id="z_Duration" value="=" />
                      <select name="x_Duration" class="tf-select">
                        <option value="" selected="selected">All Days</option>
                      </select>
                      <script type="text/javascript">
contents=new Array();
function TCN_addContent(str){
    contents.push(str);
    arrayValues = new Array();
    for(i=0;i<contents.length;i++){
        arrayValues[i]=contents[i].split(separator);
    }
}
function TCN_makeSelValueGroup(){
    selValueGroup=new Array();
    args=TCN_makeSelValueGroup.arguments;
    for(i=0;i<args.length;i++){
        selValueGroup[i]=args[i];
    }
}
function TCN_makeComboGroup(){
    comboGroup=new Array();
    args=TCN_makeComboGroup.arguments;
    for(i=0;i<args.length;i++){
        comboGroup[i]=findObj(args[i]);
    }
}
function TCN_reload(from){
thisComboStr="";
    index=-1;
    if(!from){
        index=0;
        setDefault();
    }else{
        for(j=0;j<comboGroup.length-1;j++){
            if (comboGroup[j]==from){
                index=j+1;
            }
        }
    }
    if(index!=-1){
        thisCombo=comboGroup[index];
        thisComboText=index*2;
        thisComboValue=(index*2)+1;
        if(index>0){
            for(p=0;p<index;p++){   thisComboStr+=comboGroup[p].options[comboGroup[p].selectedIndex].text+separator+comboGroup[p].options[comboGroup[p].selectedIndex].value+separator;
            }
        }
        for(m=thisCombo.options.length-1;m>=1;m--){
            thisCombo.options[m]=null;
        }
        for(i=0;i<contents.length;i++){
            existe=false;
            if(contents[i].substr(0,thisComboStr.length)==thisComboStr){
                for(j=0;j<thisCombo.options.length;j++){
                    if(arrayValues[i][thisComboText]==thisCombo.options[j].text){
                        existe=true;
                    }
                }
                if(existe==false){
                    thisCombo.options[thisCombo.options.length]=new Option(arrayValues[i][thisComboText],arrayValues[i][thisComboValue]);
                }
            }
        }
        thisCombo.options[0].selected=true;
        for (n=0;n<thisCombo.options.length;n++){
            if(thisCombo.options[n].value==selValueGroup[index]){
                thisCombo.options[n].selected=true;
            }
        } 
        TCN_reload(thisCombo);
    }
}
function setDefault(){
    for (i=selValueGroup.length-1;i>=0;i--){
        if(selValueGroup[i]!=""){
            for(j=0;j<contents.length;j++){
                if(arrayValues[j][(i*2)+1]==selValueGroup[i]){
                    for(k=i;k>=0;k--){
                        if(selValueGroup[k]==""){
                            selValueGroup[k]=arrayValues[j][(k*2)+1];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible - You would need to [load the initial drop down from the database](http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/list-table.php), and then using javascript you'd need to bind an AJAX request to the onchange event of this field.

Here are some examples, as you requested (found on [quick Googling](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=ajax+cascading+dropdown#q=php+ajax+cascading+dropdown)):

- http://www.infotuts.com/cascaded-dropdown-jquery-ajax-php/
- http://easyscript4u.blogspot.co.il/2014/04/how-to-create-cascaded-dropdown-with.html
- http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/449766/php-cascading-drop-down
- http://buffernow.com/cascading-dropdown-ajax/

Comment: Thankyou sooooo much it really helped!! I am going through the links.... I think I got it!!